# How would I add certain metadata to pdf files after using find

Tags: bash, ubuntu, find, pdf

Say I use find command to find a group of pdfs.
I want to add metadata to all of these pdfs, say **keywords** of *red* and *small*.
What command could I execute?

```
find (some criteria) -name "*.pdf" -exec (some command)
```

Note: I could also use bash script and for loop if better.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some details. First of all, what operating system are you using? And what exact metadata do you want to add? Does `color:red` actually mean something?

Comment: PDF files have a well-specified format, so to add metadata within the .pdf involves conforming to the valid format rules. Have you considered (a) Adding the keywords into the file names, (b) Creating corresponding files (maybe replace .pdf suffix with .tags), or (c) Using a separate database ?

Answer (score 4):

With [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/) (the go-to utility when it comes to manipulating file metadata):

```
find . (some criteria) -name '*.pdf' -exec exiftool -Keywords+='red, small' {} +
```

It can also do the finding by itself.

```
exiftool -r -ext pdf -Keywords+='red, small' .
```

You may also want to read [what its documentation has to say about updating PDF metadata](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html).

On Debian-based systems, `exiftool` is found in the `libimage-exiftool-perl` package.